# Is there a way I could click photos using the volume button without opening the camera app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera, photos

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 on a custom ROM. (Alliance ROM - ICS)

Is there a way I could capture photos using the volume button without opening the camera app when the phone is sleeping (Locked)

Comment: I haven't encountered any app that could do this yet. It seems looks like an uncommon use case even among spy apps.

Comment: Its possible to click a photo by pressing Volume button using an App. But how could your OS determine volume button's extra functionality without using an App? OS can't determine other than Just Increase/Decrease volume.

Comment: It would take a couple of seconds before the camera app is loaded and a picture is clicked. Is there any app, running in the background would help take pictures by hitting the volume button at any point of time.